# highstock yaxis scale factor

Tags: highcharts

How do I find the scale factor of yAxis[0]?  I cannot find in the API, but by studying the code it seems that it's available in chart.yAxis[xx].transA. However, Due to dynamic scaling, the scale factor of yAxis may change as I zoom/pan the xAxis, so where should I put the code to draw something using the current yAxis scale factor?

Comment: BTW, there seems to be a bug in Highstock. As the yAxis scales, setExtremes() and afterSetExtremes() events should trigger, but neither one is triggered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use tickPositions function http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositions

Comment: We moved one of our support ways to Stackoverflow

Comment: By "scale factor", I mean how many pixels = "1" in y value.  I don't see how tickPosition helps.

Comment: So you would like to set amount of pixels or get this value?

Comment: Yes, how can I get this scale factor automatically every time there is a change in the yAxis (including the very first time)?  Is redraw() the right place?

Comment: You can get width of xAxis and divide by amount of ticks.
http://jsfiddle.net/Z8mZc/

Comment: Thanks but I need to know the scale factor for yAxis, not xAxis. How can I do it?

Comment: In the same way as xAxis, you need to replace xAxis[0] by yAxis[0]

Comment: Do you know why neither setExtremes() nor afterSetExtremes() is triggered in yAxis.events even though the scale factor of yAxis changes (by zooming/panning in xAxis, not by directly calling yAxis.setExtremes())?  This seems a bug to me since I can't get callback when the scale factor of yAxis changed.

Comment: Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/wuz73/cyjvF/
BTW, there's another problem with highstock and jQuery1.8.3 -- the test code only works with jQuery1.7.2, but not 1.8.3 or 1.9.1